# Let $A,B$ be compact subsets of $X$. Prove that $A \cap B$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $A,B$ be compact subsets of $X$. Prove that $A \cap B$ is compact.

Attempt: Suppose by contrapositive, that  $A \cup B$ is compact. Then 
let $V$ be an open cover of $A \cup B$. Then let $A$ be compact, then $ V$ has a finite subcover of $A$ . But suppose $B$ is not compact. Then $V$ does not contain a finite subcover of $B$. Thus their union will not be have a finite subcover of $ V$ that converse $A \cup B$.

Can someone please help me? I already proved if $A, B$ are compact , then their union is compact. So I was trying to use a similar argument.
Any feedback/help would really help. Thanks

Comment: Are you working with metric spaces or in general topology? In the latter case the ambient space should be assumed Hausdorff.

Comment: i am working with a metric space X

Comment: “Suppose, by contrapositive, that $A\cap B$ is *not* compact”. However this leads nowhere.

Comment: So the best way, it to go on the forward direction?

Comment: Yes; use the fact that compact sets are closed and use mookid's hint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$A$ and $B$ compact in a hausdorff space implies $A\cap B$ is compact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707274/a-and-b-compact-in-a-hausdorff-space-implies-a-cap-b-is-compact)

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your contrapositive.

**Hint:** show that a closed part of a compact set is compact.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is Hausdorff (in particular all metrci spaces are Hausdorff), every compact subset is closed.

So, $A,B$ are closed $\Rightarrow$ $A \cap B$ is closed in $A$. But $A$ is compact, so $A\cap B$ is a closed subset of a compact set, hence it is compact.

Answer (score -1):

In any topological space if you suppose that A and B are compact then it holds that A can be written as a finite cover of open sets and so can B (definition of compactness).
So if you intersect open sets you still get open sets therefore that should be a finite cover of open sets of = (A intersection B)
and again according to defenition the intersection is compact.

ok,  this happens only in hauusdorf spaces as I have seen and it's incorrect for every space. I've seen a counter example: (intersection of two compacts isn't compact) Y-with the discrete topology Y is infinite and X is taken to be X=Y uninon {c1} union {c2}, where {c1} and {c2} are two arbitary points. The topology on X is defined to be all the open sets in Y. Now can anyone understand this counter example? It doesn't make sense...

Comment: For an easier counterexample, glue two copies of $[0,1]$ along $(0,1)$.